# Align div to bottom of containing div and wrap text around bottom div

Tags: html, css

I am struggling trying to figure out how to position #book3 at the bottom of #content-body-container and wrap the text around #book3. I can't use a top-margin on #book3 because then the text will not wrap around it.  I need the approach to be cross browser compatible and also work in older browsers.  I would like pure html/css solution if possible

fiddle available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/agola/206e2fk0/)

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    #content {
        width: 960px;
        height: 600px;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #content-body-container {
        position: relative; 
        float: left;
        top: 28px;
        width: 495px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        height: 462px;
    }

    #book3 {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        /*margin-top:117px;*/
        /*top: 145px;*/
        bottom: 0;
        height: 345px;
        width: 88px;
        background-color: #ffe3b1;
    }
    #book1 {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        top: 61px;
        bottom: 0;
        height: 429px;
        width: 79px;
        margin-right: 16px;
        background-color: #ffd48b;
    }

    #book2 {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        top: 28px;
        bottom: 0;
        height: 462px;
        width: 28px;
        margin-right: 12px;
        background-color: #ffc664;
    }

    #link-book1 {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 54px;
    }

    #link-book3 {
        position: absolute;
        margin-left: 2px;
        bottom: 16px;
    }


    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="content-body" class="content-wrapper">

            <div id="book1">
                <a href="#" id="link-book1" class="book-link">Book 1</a>
            </div>

            <div id="book2"></div>

            <div id="content-body-container">
                <div id="book3">
                    <a href="#" id="link-book3" class="book-link">Book 3</a>
                </div>
                <div id="content-body-text">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla.

                    Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh. Aenean quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique sem. Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa.

                    Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet. Mauris ipsum. Nulla metus metus, ullamcorper vel, tincidunt sed, euismod in, nibh. Quisque volutpat condimentum velit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam nec ante. Sed lacinia, urna non tincidunt mattis, tortor neque adipiscing diam, a cursus ipsum ante quis turpis. Nulla facilisi. Ut fringilla. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc feugiat mi a tellus consequat imperdiet.

                    Suspendisse in justo eu magna luctus suscipit. Integer euismod lacus luctus magna. Quisque cursus, metus vitae pharetra auctor, sem massa mattis sem, at interdum magna augue eget diam. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi lacinia molestie dui. 

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `height` of the container and the floated box is persistent, you could add a `padding-top` to the container and also add a negative `margin-top` to the block containing text to achieve the effect:

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/206e2fk0/1/)**

```css
#content-body-container {
    /* other declarations... */
    height: 462px;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    padding-top: 117px; /* 462px - 345px */
}

#content-body-text { margin-top: -117px; }
```

[`box-sizing: border-box;`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-ui/#box-sizing) is used to force the UA to calculate the `height` of the box including padding and borders.

It is [supported even in IE8](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing). However you could reduce the `height` alternatively when you add the `padding-top`.